# random Number generation using xor shift

Tags: c++, c, random, xor

I want to generate random numbers using Xor shift. I tried this example from wikipedia but it's generating random numbers like
`332584831 1855942593 -276217806 913087829 486807926`

I would like random number between 0 and the max of int.

here is the sample of code which I am using :

```
int random_state =1234;

int randomNumber()
{

int result = random_state;
result ^= result << 13;
result ^= result >> 17;
result ^= result << 5;
random_state = result;
return result;
}
```

Comment: Think about the *frequency* of 1-digit, 2-digit etc numbers that will be generated. Unless you bias the result, most of the numbers will be 9 or 10 digits. There are 10^8 positive numbers with 8 or fewer digits, and 2047483648 `int` values with 9 or 10 digits.

Comment: For something like this, you might be better off using an `unsigned int`.  That way every bit pattern is meaningful.  Alternatively, you could mask off the sign bit before returning the result.  That way you could still retain it internally.

Comment: If the seed is not zero, that generator never generates zero. If it is zero, it never generates anything else.

Answer (score -1):

It is better to use unsigned integer types when performing bit-wise logic and shift operations because the resulting values are well-defined in terms of the widths (in bits) of the unsigned types.

Assuming `unsigned int` is at least 18 bits wide and that `INT_MAX` is one less than a power of 2, then the following should work:

```
#include <limits.h>

unsigned int random_state = 1234;

int randomNumber(void)
{
    unsigned int r = random_state;
    r ^= r << 13;
    r ^= r >> 17;
    r ^= r << 5;
    random_state = r;
    return (int)(r & INT_MAX);
}
```